# GeoDjango GEOSException error

Tags: python, django, homebrew, geodjango

Trying to install a GeoDjango on my machine. I'm really new to Python and being brought into a project that has been a very tricky install for the other team members. I installed Python 2.7 and GEOS using brew, and running PSQL 9.2.4 but keep getting this error when I try to get the webserver running:

```
__import__(name)
File "/Users/armynante/Desktop/uclass-files/uclass-env/lib/python2.7/site
packages/django/contrib/gis/geometry/backend/geos.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos import (
File "/Users/armynante/Desktop/uclass-files/uclass-env/lib/python2.7/site
packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, wkt_regex, hex_regex
File "/Users/armynante/Desktop/uclass-files/uclass-env/lib/python2.7/site
packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 14, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos.coordseq import GEOSCoordSeq
File "/Users/armynante/Desktop/uclass-files/uclass-env/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/coordseq.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos.libgeos import CS_PTR
File "/Users/armynante/Desktop/uclass-files/uclass-env/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py", line 119, in <module>
_verinfo = geos_version_info()
File "/Users/armynante/Desktop/uclass-files/uclass-env/lib/python2.7/site
packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py", line 115, in geos_version_info
if not m: raise GEOSException('Could not parse version info string "%s"' % ver)
django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException: Could not parse version info string
"3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921"
```

Cant seem to find anything relevant to this trace on SO or the web. I think it might be a regex failure? I'm currently trying to reinstall PSQL and GEOS to see if I can get it running.

Here is my requirements file:

```
django==1.4
psycopg2==2.4.4
py-bcrypt==0.4
python-memcached==1.48
south==0.7.3

# Debug Tools
sqlparse==0.1.3
django-debug-toolbar==0.9.1
django-devserver==0.3.1

# Deployment
fabric==1.4

# AWS
# boto==2.1.1
django-storages==1.1.4
django-ses==0.4.1

# ECL
http://packages.elmcitylabs.com/ecl_django-0.5.3.tar.gz#ecl_django
http://packages.elmcitylabs.com/ecl_google-0.2.14.tar.gz#ecl_google
# https://packages.elmcitylabs.com/ecl_tools-0.3.7.tar.gz#ecl_tools
# https://packages.elmcitylabs.com/chargemaster-0.2.19.tar.gz
# https://packages.elmcitylabs.com/ecl_facebook-0.3.12.tar.gz#ecl_facebook
# https://packages.elmcitylabs.com/ecl_twitter-0.3.3.tar.gz#ecl_twitter

# Search
#https://github.com/elmcitylabs/django-haystack/tarball/issue-522#django-haystack
-e git+https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git#egg=django-haystack

pysolr==2.1.0-beta
# whoosh==2.3.2

# Misc
# PIL
# django-shorturls==1.0.1
# suds==0.4

django-mptt
sorl-thumbnail

stripe
pytz==2013b
```

Comment: could be an issue with the build you are using. Try to update it to a later version. More [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17212)

Comment: Yeah I saw that ticket before. I'm currently installing it again and I'll try upgrading to the next release if that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on my mac. No idea what's causing it. If you solved it please post the solution.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

This is my solution (obviously it is ugly, like my English, but works).
The problem is that the versions string has an white space unwanted in the RegEx.

The error says:

*GEOSException: Could not parse version info string "3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921"*

And the geos_version_info warns:

*Regular expression should be able to parse version strings such as
'3.0.0rc4-CAPI-1.3.3', '3.0.0-CAPI-1.4.1' or '3.4.0dev-CAPI-1.8.0'*

**Edit this file:** site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py

**Look for the function:** geos_version_info

**And change this line:**

`ver = geos_version().decode()`

**With this line:**

`ver = geos_version().decode().split(' ')[0]`

There is also another problem, where there is a whitespace at the end but no more information is provided. Such version also doesn't match version regular expression, so `strip()`-ping the version may be expected behaviour as a quick fix. In my example it was: `'3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 '`

Comment: I re-installed GEOS with the 1.9 GDAL Kyung Khaos package and PSQL1.9 and the error went away, so unfortunately I cant test this. Did it work for you, or is this just a suggestion?

Comment: This works for me, after an ArchLinux update my django code was broken.

Comment: was ver = geos_version() in the version this site is using, thanks!

Comment: I had the given error, I only upgrade my python from two to three, because my code written in python3. my problem was solved.

Answer (score 23):

In the latest GEOS install, the above answer didn't work... but was close to the problem.

I changed the regex right above the geos_version_info():
from:

```
version_regex = re.compile(r'^(?P<version>(?P<major>\d+)\.(?P<minor>\d+)\.(?P<subminor>\d+))((rc(?P<release_candidate>\d+))|dev)?-CAPI-(?P<capi_version>\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$')
```

to be:

```
version_regex = re.compile(r'^(?P<version>(?P<major>\d+)\.(?P<minor>\d+)\.(?P<subminor>\d+))((rc(?P<release_candidate>\d+))|dev)?-CAPI-(?P<capi_version>\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*$')
```

Notice the .* added to the end of the regex.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. However, the answer that is marked as accepted failed with my setup.

Comment: This worked for me (thanks!) but the accepted answer also worked for me and is probably a little more simple to apply.

Answer (score 15):

I think this is broken again. A recent upgrade on our FreeBSD server led to this error:

`django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException: Could not parse version info string "3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6"`

Looks like the regex in Django's `libgeos.py` needs to be updated again to account for this different syntax. Nachopro's solution still serves as a workaround.

Comment: Looks like there is a [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/78c155cf2e5a27fd2db18c2d46953b1b0fdba829) to fix it in Django v1.11.5

Comment: Thanks for the update, just noticed the same issue on OS X (10.11).

Comment: Yep, broken in Django 1.11.4, Python 3.6 & macOS Sierra.

Comment: For those on MacOS installing via Homebrew, I used the following to install an older version `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/d8764c105feb474b47fe291815112ae1d0fb91ef/Formula/postgis.rb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/d8764c105feb474b47fe291815112ae1d0fb91ef/Formula/geos.rb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/d8764c105feb474b47fe291815112ae1d0fb91ef/Formula/gdal.rb`

Comment: FWIW what I did was run `brew switch geos 3.6.1` as my Homebrew had kept 3.6.1 around when upgrarding it to 3.6.2 (as is default behaviour in homebrew unless you run `brew cleanup`).

Answer (score 5):

It appears that [this has been fixed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/747f7d25490abc3d7fdb119f0ce3708d450eb4c2) in Django as of last March or so. See also [Django bug 20036](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20036). So upgrading to Django 1.5.4 will solve the problem.

Comment: I'll admit my original post was based on a couple of inferences, but looking now, doesn't this indicate that the fix is in 1.4.8? https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.8/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py#L106

Comment: No, the regular expression there will not match the problematic version number. The fix is only in 1.5, I'm afraid.

Comment: As noted above in @Kirkman14 's answer, this is broken; ironically the project I'm trying to install is Django 1.5.4 but the fix I found four years ago tomorrow isn't a fix for newer versions of libgeos.  Good times!

Answer (score 5):

For those folks who don't have 3.6.1 previously installed:

1. `brew unlink geos`
2. Install 3.6.1 with `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/145b22e8330e094ee148861e72e26c03e73d34a1/Formula/geos.rb`.
3. `brew info geos` should show 3.6.1 starred:
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

Brew just released geos 3.8.0 that of course breaks Django 1.11 again.
The previous version, 3.7.3, was oh so very helpfully cleared by the all new all automatic cleanup now running on upgrades, so no `brew switch geos 3.7.3` for me.

I ended up using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formulahttps://) to understand how to find the previous version number and commit hash:

```sh
cd $( brew --prefix )/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
git log -- Formula/geos.rb | less
# find the version you need in the file, copy its hash
brew unlink geos
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/<yourcommithash>/Formula/geos.rb
```

After all this, the download for geos 3.7.3 fails SHA256 checksum validation for some reason... so I ended up trying 3.7.2, that actually worked.

For now the command to reinstall 3.7.2 on Catalina is:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/823b700ab61eeec57f34d50be2cc34a285fb5abc/Formula/geos.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

If one cannot for any reason edit the site packages themselves, this ugly hack did it for me without having to act on the environment itself:

```
try:
    __import__('django.contrib.gis.geos.libgeos', fromlist=['version_regex'])
except Exception as e:
    import re
    att = __import__('django.contrib.gis.geos.libgeos', fromlist=['version_regex'])
    setattr(att, 'version_regex', re.compile(
      '^(?P<version>(?P<major>\\d+)\\.(?P<minor>\\d+)\\.(?P<subminor>\\d+))((rc(?P<release_candidate>\\d+))|dev)?-CAPI-(?P<capi_version>\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)( r\\d+)?( \\w+)?.*$'))
    assert str(type(e)) == "<class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException'>", str(e)
```

It is based on [JayCrossler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19811665/3772123).

**Update**

The above executes code found within the `django.contrib.gis.geos.__init__.py` module, which already tries to use the problematic part, rendering the above solution unusable (for python 2.7+). This can be worked around as:

```
import sys
try:
    import django.contrib.gis.geos.libgeos
except Exception as e:
    import re
    setattr(sys.modules['django.contrib.gis.geos.libgeos'],'version_regex', re.compile(
        '^(?P<version>(?P<major>\\d+)\\.(?P<minor>\\d+)\\.(?P<subminor>\\d+))((rc(?P<release_candidate>\\d+))|dev)?-CAPI-(?P<capi_version>\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)( r\\d+)?( \\w+)?.*$'))
    assert str(type(e)) == "<class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException'>", str(e)
```

Where basically we are acting directly on the module in `sys.modules` instead of trying to get it from another import that will fail.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by trying the following,

> brew switch geos 3.6.1

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643998/geodjango-geosexception-error/45488871#comment78628369_45488871) this will only work if you still have 3.6.1 on your system from a previous installation.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by installing PostGIS with Postgres using https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html.

1. Install PostGIS (2.2): brew install postgis
2. To unlink geos if version is higher than 3.6.1: brew unlink geos
3. Install Geos (3.6.1): brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/145b22e8330e094ee148861e72e26c03e73d34a1/Formula/geos.rb
4. Switch geos version(latest version is 3.7.2 which is not supported by Django 1.11.3): brew switch geos 3.6.1
5. Login to database and create postgis extensions: CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
   Test postgis extension: SELECT ST_Distance('LINESTRING(-122.33 47.606, 0.0 51.5)'::geography, 'POINT(-21.96 64.15)'::geography);
6. Check postgis version: SELECT PostGIS_full_version();