# Django + uWSGI/nginx inside docker container - ImportError: No module named .wsgi

Tags: django, nginx, docker, uwsgi

This an ancient Django (v1.3.7) application that I'm migrating over to a Docker setup.
The basic framework comes from [this dockerfiles repo](https://github.com/dockerfiles/django-uwsgi-nginx).

I can get the app running fine using Django's built in dev server (`./manage.py runserver`), but I'd like to have this served using uWSGI/Nginx in production.

I can get uwsgi to run without errors when I call it from a bash prompt within the the container like so: `uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file /home/docker/code/siteweb/glrimon.wsgi` However, when I try to import my wsgi file from the Django shell I get the same import error.

Here is the what gets logged when I startup the container (which calls `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/docker/code/uwsgi.ini` via supervisord):

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/docker/code/uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Tue May  9 13:35:14 2017] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 05 May 2017 18:06:55
os: Linux-3.16.0-77-generic #99~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 19:17:10 UTC 2016
nodename: 222b58f8d3ea
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
chdir() to /home/docker/code/siteweb/
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 524288
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/docker/code/app.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2017/05/09 13:35:14 [debug] 11#11: epoll add event: fd:6 op:1 ev:00002001
2017/05/09 13:35:14 [debug] 12#12: epoll add event: fd:6 op:1 ev:00002001
2017/05/09 13:35:14 [debug] 11#11: epoll del event: fd:6 op:2 ev:00000000
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x8f11c0
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 415360 bytes (405 KB) for 8 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
added /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ to pythonpath.
added /usr/lib/python2.7/ to pythonpath.
added ./siteweb to pythonpath.
ImportError: No module named glrimon.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

Here is my uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
# this config will be loaded if nothing specific is specified
# load base config from below
ini = :base

# %d is the dir this configuration file is in
socket = %dapp.sock
master = true
processes = 4
threads = 2

#logging
logto=/var/log/uwsgi.log

[dev]
ini = :base
# socket (uwsgi) is not the same as http, nor http-socket
socket = :8001


[local]
ini = :base
http = :8000


[base]
# chdir to the folder of this config file, plus app/website
chdir = %dsiteweb/
# allow anyone to connect to the socket. This is very permissive
chmod-socket=666
# explicitly set python path
pythonpath = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
pythonpath = /usr/lib/python2.7
pythonpath = ./siteweb
# also referencing here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#deploying-django
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=siteweb.settings
# load the module from wsgi.py, it is a python path from
# the directory above.
module=glrimon.wsgi:application
```

Here is what my wsgi file looks like:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Dockerfiles

# Install required packages and remove the apt packages cache when done.

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    git \
    # for python package lxml
    libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev \
    # for python package PIL
    libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev \
    # for python package psycopg2
    build-essential libpq-dev \
    # for geodjango
    libgeos-dev \
    python \
    python-dev \
    python-setuptools \
    python-pip \
    nginx \
    supervisor \
    sqlite3 && \
    pip install -U pip setuptools && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install uwsgi now because it takes a little while
RUN pip install uwsgi

# setup uwsgi logging directory
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/uwsgi

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/uwsgi.log
#    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/uwsgi/req.log

# setup all the configfiles
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
COPY supervisor-app.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

# COPY requirements.txt and RUN pip install BEFORE adding the rest of your code, this will cause Docker's caching mechanism
# to prevent re-installinig (all your) dependencies when you made a change a line or two in your app.

COPY requirements.txt /home/docker/code/
RUN pip install -r /home/docker/code/requirements.txt
# workaround for missing distribution for pkg_resources
# ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources
#RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools

# deal with Geodjango GEOSexception error
# (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19811665/6072959)
RUN sed -i 's/d+)\$/d+)\.\*\$/g' \
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py

# add (the rest of) our code
# skip this step since the code is actually referenced via
# symlink since it's gigantic
# connect a volume to the code during docker run instead
COPY . /home/docker/code/

WORKDIR /home/docker/code

# install django, normally you would remove this step because your project would already
# be installed in the code/siteweb/ directory
#RUN django-admin.py startproject website /home/docker/code/siteweb/

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

Any thoughts/ideas are always appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be because of chdir stuff. This part `chdir = %dsiteweb/`, can you change it to `chdir = /home/docker/code/siteweb/` and try?

Comment: I'll give that a try, but in the logfile I posted there is this line (`chdir() to /home/docker/code/siteweb/`) which leads me to believe that setting is working as it should.

Comment: Same result as before. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ideas.

1. I wonder if `pythonpath = ./siteweb` is relative to the initial current working directory? When you run it manually, are you already in `/home/docker/code`? Try adding the following to the `Dockerfile`:

   ```
   WORKDIR /home/docker/code
   ```
2. Is module the correct option for the ini file? According to uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html if you are using --wsgi-file /home/docker/code/siteweb/glrimon.wsgi on the command line you should probably also have wsgi-file /home/docker/code/siteweb/glrimon.wsgi in the ini file. Their example has ` module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler() as well. But since you are loading a wsgi file, that is probably not needed (it is probably one or the other).

Comment: This did not seem to work either. I get the same ImportError on startup, and when I try to access the site I see `--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---` I'll add my dockerfile to the original question.

Comment: Is `module` the correct option for the ini file? According to http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html if you are using `--wsgi-file /home/docker/code/siteweb/glrimon.wsgi` on the command line you should probably also have `wsgi-file /home/docker/code/siteweb/glrimon.wsgi` in the ini file. Their example has ` `module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()` as well. But since you are loading a wsgi file, that is probably not needed (it is probably one or the other).

Comment: This suggestion has been helpful, or at least it produced a different error (similar to the issue described here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/). I have resolved that issue, but now there appears to be an issue with Django. I'll mark this as correct since it appears to have alleviated the initial error I described. Thanks for the help.