# PointField() Not Working correctly in GeoDjango

Tags: django, geodjango

I have GDAL (using `homebrew`) and SQLite installed. I would like to create a teacher with a PointField() which stores long and lat values, to know their location. Later I plan on adding the ability to search by distance using something like:

```
Teacher.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(your_location,D(m=distance))).distance(your_location).order_by('distance')
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    location = gis_models.PointField()
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

However, when I run the server, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function
check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x111c619d8>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
line 227, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
line 117, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
line 250, in raise_last_exception
        six.reraise(*_exception)
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py",
line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
line 227, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py",
line 27, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
line 108, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
line 202, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py",
line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/Users/gr/Desktop/PycharmProjects/DjangoWebsite/users/models.py",
line 2, in <module>
        from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py",
line 3, in <module>
        from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/aggregates.py",
line 1, in <module>
        from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import ExtentField
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py",
line 3, in <module>
        from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py",
line 3, in <module>
        from .fields import (  # NOQA
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py",
line 4, in <module>
        from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py",
line 18, in <module>
        HAS_GEOS = geos_version_info()['version'] >= '3.3.0'
      File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py",
line 196, in geos_version_info
        raise GEOSException('Could not parse version info string "%s"' % ver)
    django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException: Could not parse version info string "3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6"
```

Comment: did you look for the same trouble? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643998/geodjango-geosexception-error and the ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28441 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, which has been fixed and will be rolled out in [Django v1.11.5](https://github.com/django/django/pull/8841/commits/a49764dd9daa11c4e24bad84423f71711b3e0de0).

If you can't wait for 1.11.5 or don't want to run on the dev branch, you can go to a previous version of geos:

```
brew switch geos 3.6.1
```

Comment: Thanks, I get: Error: geos does not have a version "3.6.1" in the Cellar.