# django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException: Could not parse version info string

Tags: python, django, gdal

I installed `gdal` on Mac as follows:

```
brew install -v gdal
```

However when I run my program (which I was able to successfully run on Linux), it gives me the following errors:

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/tesor/Desktop/test/api-server/api-server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.options import GeoModelAdmin, OSMGeoAdmin
  File "/Users/tesor/Desktop/test/api-server/api-server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin/options.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.widgets import OpenLayersWidget
  File "/Users/tesor/Desktop/test/api-server/api-server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin/widgets.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
  File "/Users/tesor/Desktop/test/api-server/api-server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    HAS_GEOS = geos_version_info()['version'] >= '3.3.0'
  File "/Users/tesor/Desktop/test/api-server/api-server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py", line 196, in geos_version_info
    raise GEOSException('Could not parse version info string "%s"' % ver)
django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException: Could not parse version info string "3.6.3-CAPI-1.10.3 80c13047"
```

I cannot figure out what's happening. The version of python is `Python 2.7.15`. I understand that the issue is related to the version of GDAL, but  how can I solve this problem?
I need `gdal 1.10.1`.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643998/geodjango-geosexception-error

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to make sure I was running python 3.

I exited my pipenv and re-entered it. Also doublecheck [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) is properly installed.

Comment: I don't see how this is a solution, the question states python 2.7 is being used.

Comment: I qualified it 'the fix for me'. I'm interested in helping others. Sorry it doesn't help the OP.